# You don't know JS book, softening 'this' binding

Tags: javascript

The book YDKJS contains a section describing a [soft binding](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md#softening-binding) utiliy:

```
if (!Function.prototype.softBind) {
    Function.prototype.softBind = function(obj) {
        var fn = this,
            curried = [].slice.call( arguments, 1 ),
            bound = function bound() {
                return fn.apply(
                    (!this ||
                        (typeof window !== "undefined" &&
                            this === window) ||
                        (typeof global !== "undefined" &&
                            this === global)
                    ) ? obj : this,
                    curried.concat.apply( curried, arguments )
                );
            };
        bound.prototype = Object.create( fn.prototype );
        return bound;
    };
}
```

I am unable to understand the line: `curried.concat.apply( curried, arguments )`. Why are we concatenating already curried arguments with the 
arguments object instead of simply using the curried array:

```
...
        ) ? obj : this,
        curried
    );
};
bound.prototype = Object.create( fn.prototype );
...
```

Comment: Do you understand how `bind` works with arguments?

Comment: This is an absolutely horrible implementation of whatever functionality this tried to achieve. Better forget it.

Comment: I understand how bind works, but referring to above snippet is it true that
 `curried.concat.apply( curried, arguments )` will result in fn recieving an extra set of 'arguments' while we only intend to pass 'curried' arguments?

Comment: No, `bind` works exactly the same: `const f = console.log.bind(console, "Hello"); f("World");`

Comment: Notice that `curried` comes from the `arguments` of the call to `softBind` (like "Hello" in my example) while the other `arguments` are from the call to the bound function (like "World" in my example).

Comment: Written with modern syntax (and leaving out the receiver): `function bind(fn, ...args1) { return function(...args2) { return fn(...args1, ...args2); }; }`

Comment: "Notice that curried comes from the arguments of the call to softBind... " and that's  my lightbulb moment. Thanks @Bergi

Comment: Hi I don't know ` curried = [].slice.call( arguments, 1 )`,`[].slice`return a new array,but call method only eligible for function,not for array.Why this happens?@Bergi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call a bound function, it is first passed the bound arguments, then the new argument from the call to the bound version.

i.e.

```js
function log(a, b, c, d, e) {
    console.log([a, b, c, d, e]);
}

log(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

const bound = log.bind(null, 1, 2, 3);

bound(4, 5);
```

If you didn't concatinate the bound and new arguments, then you could only get 1, 2, and 3 logged.

Comment: You might want to add that the implementation is broken, it doesn't work when you pass an array.